# Google Maps Api - MarkerWithLabel

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working on a relatively simple map with multiple markers on it. I use markerwithlabel.js to add label to my markers and almost have it working as wanted. There is only a simple problem. The labelContent gives every maker a number as wanted, only it skips the first one. This is part of the code used.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: locations[i].latlng,
            map: map,
            labelContent: i,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 0),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}

        });
```

this is what i get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UqSg.jpg

As you can see there's one little red block empty. This really is the first item. Why does it skip this item and starts counting from the second?

Hope this is a little bit clear and someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make the label content a string.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: locations[i].latlng,
        map: map,
        labelContent: ""+i,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 0),
        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
        labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}

    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is almost perfect only now it starts with 0 instead of 1. So i get 0, 1, 2, 3, ect.

Comment: Well... what did you expect?  `i` starts at 0. If you want your label value to be `i` + 1, you need to do that.